# How to solve docker container latency

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, latency

I have a VPS with docker installed running a game server.. I have a problem: I can't connect to MariaDB 10.5.5 running on the same machine (out of docker container) with address bound to `127.0.0.1` but if I bind the address to `0.0.0.0` I can connect but HikariCP or any other mysql connector took `3000ms` to connect.. Does to solve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Comment: the page i pasted maybe help.When you bind address to 0.0.0.0,your docker will access mysql via public network, so it is lag.

Answer (score 0):

3 second lag sounds like a DNS timeout. Add `skip_name_resolve=1` to your my.cnf's `[mysqld]` section.

Comment: Not solved It yet. I tried connecting from docker container to docker container and tooks 4000ms using docker0

Comment: Are your GRANTs by hostname or IP? Are you specifying the target by hostname or IP? What DNS server is specified on each of the containers? Make sure everything uses IP addresses instead of hostnames. Can you telnet to target on port 3306? How long before you get  response with server protocol version?